# Correcting double anchor tags in Rails source view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated the link below in my Ruby on Rails app which works fine but I do not like the output when I viewed the source code:

```
<li class="nav-item nav-item-cta last"><a> <%= link_to('Post Job', new_path , :class => 'btn btn-cta btn-cta-secondary' )%> </a></li>
```

It returns the following output:

```
<li class="nav-item nav-item-cta last"><a> <a class="btn btn-cta btn-cta-secondary" href="/new">Post Job</a> </a></li>
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong for the output to have resulted to showing two HTML  tags which defines a hyperlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `link_to` helper method inside an anchor tag `<a>`, use either one.

You should change from,

```
<li class="nav-item nav-item-cta last"><a> <%= link_to('Post Job', new_path , :class => 'btn btn-cta btn-cta-secondary' )%> </a></li>
```

to this,

```
<li class="nav-item nav-item-cta last"><%= link_to('Post Job', new_path , :class => 'btn btn-cta btn-cta-secondary' )%></li>
```

Notice that I removed `<a>...</a>` tag.